# How to make ssh receive the password from stdin

Tags: ssh, passwords, stdin

How can you make SSH read the password from stdin, which it doesn't do by default?

Comment: Related: [pass password to su/sudo/ssh](http://stackoverflow.com/q/233217/95735)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't with most SSH clients. You can work around it with by using SSH API's, like [Paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) for Python. Be careful not to overrule all security policies.

Comment: Any idea why it doesn't work? Intuitively it should.

Comment: It shouldn't work, because that would inspire junior sysadmins to write scripts with the SSH password entangled within the logic in the script. In an environment for network and system administration, there needs to be a clear separation between security-sensitive information on the one hand and getting things done on the other. Password authentication is just not safe enough. Since ssh is widely used in sysadmin contexts, trying to keep users away from password-only security is a good idea.

Answer (score 28):

based on this [post](http://andre.frimberger.de/index.php/linux/reading-ssh-password-from-stdin-the-openssh-5-6p1-compatible-way/) you can do:

Create a command which open a ssh session using **SSH_ASKPASS** (seek SSH_ASKPASS on [man ssh](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ssh%201))

```
$ cat > ssh_session <<EOF
export SSH_ASKPASS="/path/to/script_returning_pass"
setsid ssh "your_user"@"your_host"
EOF
```

**NOTE:** To avoid ssh to try to ask on tty we use [setsid](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setsid)

Create a script which returns your password (note **echo "echo**)

```
$ echo "echo your_ssh_password" > /path/to/script_returning_pass
```

Make them executable

```
$ chmod +x ssh_session
$ chmod +x /path/to/script_returning_pass
```

try it

```
$ ./ssh_session
```

Keep in mind that ssh stands for secure shell, and if you store your user, host and password in plain text files you are misleading the tool an creating a possible security gap

Comment: Another requirement is that DISPLAY must be set.  If you are running X, you won't notice.  If you aren't, you will.  To make the ssh_script above more portable, add this:  export DISPLAY; DISPLAY=dummy

Comment: furthermore (or if you don't have setsid) -  in addition to setting DISPLAY and SSH_ASKPASS, you may also need to direct STDIN from /dev/null to convince ssh-add that it's not on a terminal:  ssh-add /path/to/key < /dev/null

Comment: I used this idea for getting the passphrase from `pass`, to give to `ssh-add` in a generic way, generating the askpass script as needed.  https://milosophical.me/blog/2018/ssh-pass.html

Comment: can someone update the solution to take in the suggestions from the comments?

Comment: On MacOS Ventura, you can also set `SSH_ASKPASS_REQUIRE` to `force` is that the `$SSH_ASKPASS` is always called regardless of whether `DISPLAY` is set.

Answer (score 17):

You can use [sshpass](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/) which is for example in the offical [debian repositories](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/sshpass). Example:

```
$ apt-get install sshpass
$ sshpass -p 'password' ssh username@server
```

Comment: sadly this is the only solution I use, which isn't great for ssh jumphosts. The alternative is `expect`, which I'm guessing is more trouble than it's work.

Comment: Homebrew (macOS) has banned it :( "
We won't add sshpass because it makes it too easy for novice SSH users to
ruin SSH's security."

Comment: @mike aren't you glad that the Homebrew maintainers are bolstering worldwide security by saving us from ourselves?  

Comment: Ha ha, yes!   I ended up writing my own hack: https://milosophical.me/blog/2018/ssh-pass.html.  YMMV

Answer (score 6):

Distilling [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15090479) leaves a simple and generic script:

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ $1 =~ password: ]] && cat || SSH_ASKPASS="$0" DISPLAY=nothing:0 exec setsid "$@"
```

Save it as `pass`, do a `chmod +x pass` and then use it like this:

```
$ echo mypass | pass ssh user@host ...
```

If its first argument contains `password:` then it passes its input to its output (`cat`) otherwise it launches whatver was presented after setting itself as the `SSH_ASKPASS` program.

When `ssh` encounters both `SSH_ASKPASS` AND `DISPLAY` set, it will launch the program referred to by `SSH_ASKPASS`, passing it the prompt `user@host's password:`

Comment: You may need to also pass `-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no` to the `ssh` command, if you haven't SSH'd into this host before; otherwise it'll prompt the user for whether they trust the unknown host key. Obviously, only do this if you're _sure_ that you trust the unknown host key.

Answer (score 5):

An old post reviving...

I found this one while looking for a solution to the exact same problem, I found something and I hope someone will one day find it useful:

1. Install **ssh-askpass** program (apt-get, yum ...)
2. Set the `SSH_ASKPASS` variable (`export SSH_ASKPASS=/usr/bin/ssh-askpass`)
3. From a terminal open a new ssh connection without an undefined TERMINAL variable (`setsid ssh user@host`)

This looks simple enough to be secure but did not check yet (just using in a local secure context).

Here we are.

Answer (score 4):

[FreeBSD mailing list](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2005-March/082301.html) recommends the [expect](http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.15/Expect.pod) library.

If you need a programmatic ssh login, you really ought to be [using public key logins](http://wp.uberdose.com/2006/10/16/ssh-automatic-login/), however -- obviously there are a lot fewer security holes this way as compared to using an external library to pass a password through `stdin`.

Answer (score 4):

a better `sshpass` alternative is :
https://github.com/clarkwang/passh

I got problems with `sshpass`, if ssh server is not added to my `known_hosts` `sshpass` will not show me any message, `passh` do not have this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure the reason you need this functionality but it seems you can get this behavior with ssh-keygen.

It allows you to login to a server without using a password by having a private RSA key on your computer and a public RSA key on the server.

http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html

Answer (score 0):

Automatically load ssh keys :
Add to .bashrc and configure environment variable.

```bash
export SSH_DIR="${HOME}/.ssh"
command mkdir -p "${SSH_DIR}"
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)" >/dev/null 2>&1
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}"
export SSH_AGENT_LIFE=14400 # 4 hours
export SSHADD_OPTS=""
export PASS_SSH_ENTRY_PREFIX="_ssh"
if command -v pass &>/dev/null \
&& command -v gpg &>/dev/null \
; then
  for _public_key in "${SSH_DIR}"/*.pub ; do
    _private_key="${_public_key%.pub}"
    _entry="$(basename "${_private_key}")"
    if command pass ls "${PASS_SSH_ENTRY_PREFIX}/${_entry}" &>/dev/null ; then
      if ! command ssh-add -l | command grep -qF -- "$(command ssh-keygen -lf "${_public_key}")" &>/dev/null ; then
        _ask="${SSH_DIR}/ssh-askpass.sh"
        (\
          echo '#!/usr/bin/env -S bash -euo pipefail' ; \
          echo ; \
          echo "command pass '${PASS_SSH_ENTRY_PREFIX}/${_entry}/password' | command head -n 1" \
        ) > "${_ask}"
        command chmod u+x "${_ask}"
        DISPLAY="${DISPLAY:-dummy}" \
        SSH_ASKPASS_REQUIRE=force \
        SSH_ASKPASS="${_ask}" \
        command ssh-add -t "${SSH_AGENT_LIFE}" ${SSHADD_OPTS:-} "${_private_key}"
      fi
    fi
  done
  command rm -f "${_ask}"
  unset _public_key _private_key _entry _ask
  #echo ; ssh-add -l
fi
```

My pass ssh entries:
`$ pass _ssh/`

```
_ssh
└── id_termux
    ├── cipher
    ├── note
    ├── password
    ├── privateKey.priv
    └── publicKey.pub
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?