# passing the password as a parameter in a scp command 

Tags: scp

how can i pass the password along with the scp command.when we use the scp protocol, it prompts us for the password.But i want to pass it as a parameter.Is that possible without using the key generation techniques?

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 3):

What you want to achieve is not possible without using keys, or heavy duty scripting of the terminal.

Why don't you want to use keys? It's the easiest most secure solution to your problem.

Also take a look at:
[How to make ssh receive the password from stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340366/how-to-make-ssh-receive-the-password-from-stdin)

Many scripting languages have modules that let you interact with ssh. If you're familiar with Perl you could take a look at the Net::SSH family of modules at CPAN:
http://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH2

Comment: @rushi When an answer is useful, upvote it. If it answers your question, mark it the official answer of this question by clicking the star.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use public/private key authentication. on ubuntu this works like described here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys

note: other -nix flavors should work in a similar.

Comment: yeah but i don't want to use ssh keys.In my script i have to pass the password as the argument to the scp command.is that possible??

Comment: But will work if i ll pass on a file containing the password??

Comment: What scripting language are you planning on using?

Comment: with scp you can't pass the password, unfortunately...
maybe there is a workaround using the [-o ssh_option] option of scp
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man1/scp.1.html

Comment: i am using the python script..

Answer (score -3):

Can you check if this works -

```
<username>:<password>@<host>
```