# Execute ssh with password authentication via windows command prompt

Tags: windows, ssh, command-line, passwords

I need to execute **ssh** from **windows command line** by providing password in a non interactive manner. I could implement the key based authentication and able to execute the ssh commands just like

```
ssh <user>@<host> <command>
```

Is there any commands like

```
ssh <user>@<host> -P <password> <command>
```

[image]

I don't know if it is feasible. However, there can be some work around for the same. Throw me some ideas to accomplish the same.

Comment: Using key-based authentication is a much better idea.

Comment: Yeah i have a requirement for password based authentication too.

Comment: @GregInozemtsev while that the case, sometimes the need arises for a quick-and-dirty script to do something like this, especially in a testing or other environment where pure security isn't required.

Comment: I don't figure out why is missing that basic option. I was looking for -pw superputty (putty) command :(

I guess i will move to ssh keys instead.

Comment: its so stupid they forgot to add a password argument. have windows developers never used ssh? there are so many scenarios where password is fine. particularly in dev environments with no secret data. just so stupid that people dont actually think about this essential use case, and waste so much productivity time like this.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

PuTTY's plink has a [command-line argument for a password](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.62/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink-usage).  Some other suggestions have been made in [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1340366/163956): using Expect (which is available for Windows), or writing a launcher in Python with Paramiko.

Answer (score 146):

The [sshpass](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/) utility is meant for exactly this. First, install sshpass by typing this command:

```
sudo apt-get install sshpass
```

Then prepend your ssh/scp command with

```
sshpass -p '<password>' <ssh/scp command>
```

This program is easiest to install when using Linux.

User should consider using SSH's more secure public key authentication (with the `ssh` command) instead.

Comment: Not entirely sure how a linux utility (that can be make'd for Cygwin, but that is a whole different level of sysadmining) gets 64 up-votes... and Plink which does exactly what the OP asked and doesn't require any additional work (and is probably already installed on their system in the first place) gets 1.

I tend to trust Stack on these things, so if there is a good reason to jump through the generally annoying and occasionally maddening hoops of make... er... I am genuinely curious why it got so much love.

Comment: Because the title does not include "windows" and it shows high in the list when search for this for Linux/Unix/Mac.  So, answering this question here saves time.

Comment: It sure saved me time. On OS X, you can't get this with Homebrew except from an unofficial repo, which is easy to find.

Comment: Worked great in Mac OS X.  I installed sshpass via `sudo port install sshpass`.

Though, if there is a problem logging in due to something else, sshpass tended to fail silently (no error message).  So debug the command without `sshpass` first; then add `sshpass -p blah` (etc.).

Comment: You should be aware that executed shell commands get stored (for example in '.bash_history') ..

Comment: Anish - The author asked for windows, you gave option for linux.

Comment: In order to run sshpass in Linux CentOS you must `yum -y install epel-release` and then `yum -y install sshpass`

Comment: @arka.b, As Frobbit said, this shows high in the search results for "specify password in ssh command" for example, and the OP didn't state for a Windows answer.

Comment: @Benjamin Then prepend a space to a command, it won't be stored then.

Comment: How is this an acceptable answer to a question that's related to windows ssh?

Answer (score 25):

**Windows** Solution

1. Install [PuTTY](https://putty.org/)
2. Press `Windows-Key + R`
3. Enter `putty.exe -ssh [username]@[hostname] -pw [password]`

Answer (score 24):

What about this expect script?

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh root@myhost
expect -exact "root@myhost's password: "
send -- "mypassword\r"
interact
```

Comment: It says I do not have the expect script

Comment: `expect` is notoriously underrated!

Comment: this is a LINUX solution the question is about WINDOWS!!!

Answer (score 6):

**PowerShell solution**

Using Posh-SSH:

```
New-SSHSession -ComputerName 0.0.0.0 -Credential $cred | Out-Null
Invoke-SSHCommand -SessionId 1 -Command "nohup sleep 5 >> abs.log &" | Out-Null
```

Comment: Only works with PowerShell 6 (not Core versions)

Answer (score 5):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57479820) is a valid solution for your issue.

1. Install PuTTY on your Windows Machine
2. Execute 'plink your_username@yourhost -pw your_password'

If you use the Windows Terminal and you want your shell to log into a remote machine when opening a new tab, you may configure the command line params (Settings -> Shell -> Command line):

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\Microsoft.PowerShell.ID\pwsh.exe
-Command "plink USERNAME@192.168.0.1 -pw PASSWORD"
```

Comment: PowerShell Core must be installed from app store, or using .msixbundle from GitHub releases page https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Owain Esau, but I suggest using sshsessions module

```html
try{
    import-module sshsessions -ea stop
    $continue =  $true
    }
catch{
    $continue =  $false
    }

[string][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]$ComputerName = 'cvmbox-cmx.mydomx.com'   
[string][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]$username = "root"
[string][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]$password = 'Super$ecretP@ssw0rd'
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username,$securePassword

function Nu-Connect($Credentials, $computerName) {
    remove-SshSession -RemoveAll -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
    $varsession = New-SshSession -ComputerName $computerName -Credential $Credentials
    $IsConnected = Get-SSHSession
    Write-Output "Connected to $($IsConnected.computername)"     
    return $varsession
}
if($continue){
    Nu-Connect -ComputerName $ComputerName -Credentials $credential

    $command = "df"
    $df = (Get-SshSession -ComputerName $ComputerName | Invoke-SshCommand -Command $command -Quiet).result 
    $df
}
else {
    write-host "SSH module not found in Host : $($env:computername)"
    }
```