# How to install sshpass on Windows through Cygwin?

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin, sshpass

In the packages window of CygWin, when I type sshpass, nothing comes up. I tried installing similar packages like openssh etc hoping one of them contains sshpass but no luck.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

sshpass is not available as Cygwin package. This means that you need to build and install from source.  To build [sshpass](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass) on Windows (Cygwin):

```
$ curl -LO http://downloads.sourceforge.net/sshpass/sshpass-1.06.tar.gz
$ md5sum sshpass-1.06.tar.gz
f59695e3b9761fb51be7d795819421f9
```

Build and install to `/usr/local/bin`:

```
$ tar xvf sshpass-1.06.tar.gz
$ cd sshpass-1.06
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Which installs two files

- the executable `/usr/local/bin/sshpass`
- man page `/usr/local/share/man/man1/sshpass.1`

Your Cygwin install needs to have the required tools: `curl` to download, `tar` to extract, and `autoconf`, `make` and `gcc` to build. I'll assume reader familiarity with installing packages on Cygwin.

Comment: @Andrew do share your experience... I found that I [lost output](https://superuser.com/questions/1193146) when I used `sshpass `from a Windows *Command Prompt*. It works fine from a Cygwin terminal, however.

Comment: If you wish to use `sshpass` from a Windows command prompt then [you may find `cygnative` useful](https://superuser.com/a/1199954).

Comment: I found that I don't even have `sudo` installed in cygwin, but I was able to get it going without `sudo`.. :)

Comment: @tplive Can you please elaborate on how you did it?

Comment: I see this. http://www.cygwin.com/packages/summary/sshpass.html . I just ran ```C:\p2\cygpacks\setup-x86_64.exe -q -n -N -d -R c:\p2\cygwin64 -l c:\p2\cygpacks\cygwin64localpackages  -s http://cygwin.mirror.constant.com -P sshpass ``` .  It installed sshpass.

Answer (score 8):

sshpass is not available as cygwin package. This means that you need to build and install from source.
See for reference on existing alternative

https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2015-02/msg00042.html

Comment: Thanks matzeri for reply. How can I build and install on Windows? Could you refer me to some tutorial.

Answer (score 7):

This does not directly answer the question "How to install sshpass on Windows?", but can be much easier solution if you need to automatically enter the password when ssh-ing to a machine on Windows system, you can use Plink (part of PuTTY).

```
plink your_username@yourhost -pw your_password
```

Answer (score 0):

Window 10 comes with Linux subsystem, you can install a favor of Linux through Windows Store. Then all Linux commands comes easily. sshpass can be easily installed in the subsystem. WSL(Windwos Subsystem for Linux) is the future.

Comment: Sure, but I shouldn't need to start (or set up, if I don't have one) a WSL installation, just to automatically use a password with SSH, if I already have a working SSH client on Windows.