# ssh via python subprocess: how to bail if fingerprint absent (Are you sure you want to continue connecting?)

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess

I'm using a python script to manage ssh fingerprint problems after a workstation(s) is reimaged.

I attempt to connect, and if I get a "REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!" error, then script removes the old fingerprint, scans for the new one and adds it.

This all works great, until I get a message like this:

```
 Warning: the ECDSA host key for 'workstation-1-s' differs from the key for the IP address '192.168.1.132'
Offending key for IP in /home/me/.ssh/known_hosts:16
Matching host key in /home/me/.ssh/known_hosts:60
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

The script waits for user input before continuing and removing the offending key.

How can I get the script to push through, or enter "no" so the script can continue with its fingerprint repair job?

Here's the relevant method:

```
def ssh_fingerprint_changed(node):
    """
    Checks if a node's ssh fingerprint has changed or an old key is found, which can occur when a node is reimaged.
    It does this by attempting to connect via ssh and inspecting stdout for an error message.
    :param node: the ip or hostname of the node
    :return: True if the node's fingerprint doesn't match the client's records. Else False.
    """
    cmd = ["ssh", "-q", ADMIN_USER + "@" + node, "exit"]
    completed = subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    if completed.stdout.find("REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!") == -1:
        print("REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!")
        return True
    elif completed.stdout.find("Offending key") == -1:
        print("Offending key found.") # need to type "no" before this prints
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: you need `Popen` with stdin redirected and provide `no` when you meet the message. Note that I have hacked my version of `plink` to get rid of some interactive stuff. But it's not safe.

Comment: Can you provide an example with `Popen`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`run` (or legacy `call`) doesn't allow your controlling of the input/output of the process interactively. When you get the output, the process has already ended. So you're too late for the party.

Some would direct you to `pexpect`, or `paramiko` (which doesn't require calling `ssh` command).

Here's a workaround with `Popen`. I dropped your `return` logic. If you want to keep that, remember that at this point the process is still running, so you have to kill it (or wait for it to complete):

```
cmd = ["ssh", "-q", ADMIN_USER + "@" + node, "exit"]
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
# loop on lines
for l in p.stdout:
    if b"Offending key" in l:
        print("Offending key found.")
        p.stdin.write(b"no\n")   # provide no + newline as the answer
rc = p.wait()  # wait for process to end, get return code
```

if you're sure that the only answer will be "no", and a given number of times, an alternative to the loop would be

```
out,err = p.communicate(b"no\n"*10)  # send 10 times no+linefeed
```

note the "b" prefix when scanning strings/writing data, as standard input/output/error are binary. Doesn't matter in python 2, but in python 3, omitting the `b` compares strings with bytes, and you'll never get a match.

Aside, I've done that with `plink` on Windows, but after a while, I got tired and rebuilt a version of `plink` with all security messages disabled/defaulting to the "optimistic" value. If the network is a company network behind firewalls and you're going to answer anything to get pass those prompts, better create a non-interactive tool from the start.

Comment: looking through the `Popen` docs, it suggests using  `Popen.communicate`.  Would that be better? https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate

Comment: no because communicate doesn't allow you to filter the output line by line and decide what to reply. If you know that you're going to answer "no" a given number of times, then it's possible with comunicate.

Comment: why the b in `b"Offending key` for the strings? doesn't `universal_newlines=True` cause `stdout` to be strings?

Comment: it's different. It's CR+LF / LF conversion. Output is still `bytes` if using python 3.

Comment: Last Q!  Can make a new question if you prefer.  Now I'm getting caught on the password request (if "offending key" is NOT found) but I can't `proc.terminate()` after the loop because it never reaches past the loop?

Comment: this question can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118308/execute-ssh-with-password-authentication-via-windows-command-prompt. It seems that it says pretty much what I advised (using pexpect or plink to pass the password as a command line argument)

Comment: I don't want to provide the password though, I just want to kill the process (if it asks for password without finding the errors, I know the fingerprints are good).  I'm only running ssh to check for errors and fixing keys.

Comment: in that case, same technique. But maybe you have to read char by char because iterating on a line won't work (password prompt doesn't issue a newline). I've done a similar thing at work. Ping me in a few days (in a week day) I'll provide a char-by-char alternative.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48469916/ssh-via-python-subprocess-popen-terminate-if-password-requested

Comment: I can't answer right now, but will keep on eye on that question after the weekend. If noone answered, I will try to.