# ssh via python subprocess.Popen: terminate if password requested

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess

I'm using a python script to manage ssh fingerprint problems after a workstation(s) is reimaged.

I attempt to connect with ssh, and if I get a any warnings I deal with them.

However, if there are no errors, then I am asked for a password to connect.  At this point I want to terminate the process.  However, the script hangs on the password request.

Here's the method:

```
def ssh_fingerprint_changed(node):
    """
    Checks if a node's ssh fingerprint has changed or an old key is found, which can occur when a node is reimaged.
    It does this by attempting to connect via ssh and inspecting stdout for an error message.
    :param node: the ip or hostname of the node
    :return: True if the node's fingerprint doesn't match the client's records. Else False.
    """
    changed = False
    cmd = ["ssh", "-q", ADMIN_USER + "@" + node, "exit"]
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    print("Checking for fingerprint changes")

    for line in proc.stdout:  # loop on lines
        print("in for loop") # NEVER REACHES HERE IF NO ERRORS, WAITING FOR PASSWORD
        if b"Offending key" in line:
            print("Offending key found.")
            proc.stdin.write(b"no\n")   # don't connect
            changed = True
        elif b"REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!" in line:
            print("REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!")
            changed = True

    print(changed) # NEVER REACHES HERE IF NO ERRORS, WAITING FOR PASSWORD
    if not changed:  # then everything's good, but it will be waiting for a password to connect
        print("Good to go, terminating ssh test.")
        rc = proc.terminate()
    else:
        rc = proc.wait()

    return changed
```

If I run this from the terminal `./my_python_script.py`, I have the problems.  Oddly, if I run in PyCharm, it doesn't hang on the password request and terminates shh, continuing with the script as expected.

Comment: To explain the "why" of it -- a line with no newline will reach the loop.

Comment: As for the how to fix it -- why not just pass ssh the appropriate command-line arguments to disable password authentication?

Comment: (That said, have you considered using Paramiko instead? Much more control that way).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your "why"?.  Also I don't want to disable password authentication, I don't even want to connect here. I just need the errors/warning to remove old key prints and add new ones.

Comment: Think about it -- the password prompt leaves the cursor at the end of the line on which the prompt is printed, so even if it's printed to stdout rather than direct to the TTY, it isn't printed as a complete line. And if it's not a complete line, then `for line in file` will never iterate over it.

Comment: did you mean it will NOT reach the loop if there is no new line?  If it does reach the loop, then why no output?

Comment: That's what I meant, yes. Seriously -- use paramiko. Trying to drive an interactive program through an interface that wasn't intended for programmatic use is inherently fragile.

Comment: "a line with no newline will reach the loop"  I think you meant "will NOT reach the loop"? if so, that makes sense!

Comment: Correct, I meant will NOT reach the loop. A line is only complete if it has a newline after it. No complete line -> reading program sits around waiting for a complete line to finish printing.

Comment: That said, you're saying you want to exit when the password prompt is printed. If that's the case, why are you also saying that you "don't want to disable password authentication"? If you don't want to enter a password, why do you insist that you want ssh to emit a password prompt?

Comment: BTW, you can also tell ssh to not even ask if the user wants to accept the new key via command line arguments, thus preventing that prompt as well (but still getting the error message to read). If I correctly understand what you're doing, there shouldn't be any need for the program you're writing to write to the ssh process's stdin.

Comment: "why do you insist that you want ssh to emit a password prompt?"  I don't.  I don't care about the prompt in this case, it just happens if all the fingerprints are good. I don't want to open to man in the middle stuff by constantly connecting to all my nodes this way?

Comment: "No complete line -> reading program sits around waiting for a complete line to finish printing"  So I should be able to detect this before the for loop, right?  If I can do that, then I can solve the problem.

Comment: That depends. If you read a byte at a time, then yes, you can read incomplete lines, but that's inefficient and ugly. Otherwise you need to enable non-blocking mode, and that's its own kind of pain.

Comment: "open to man in the middle stuff"? Huh? If you enable strict host key checking, how are you vulnerable to MITM?

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer is simply to tell `ssh` that you don't want to support password authentication at all; you'll still get the messages you want if the host key is changed, but you won't ever have the process hanging waiting for a password to be entered.

```
cmd = ['ssh',
       '-o', 'PasswordAuthentication no',  ### <-- THIS LINE HERE
       '-o', 'StrictHostKeyChecking yes',  ### also, never modify known_hosts
       '-q',
       '%s@%s' % (ADMIN_USER, + node),
       'exit']
```

If you did not want to process other prompts, I would suggest setting `stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL` (in Python 3) or passing the `-n` argument to ssh to prevent stdin from being passed to the process at all.