# Need to override password when SSH from Linux to Windows

Tags: windows, ssh, passwords

I'm trying to set up an automated script from the Windows terminal that gets started from a Linux machine. The guys in my IT department have already set up a virtual SSH server on those Windows machines but they say they can't set a passwordless SSH to due to security reasons.

So I guess my question is two-fold:

1.) Is there something similar I can set up on these Windows machines that will allow me to connect to them through a Linux terminal that won't require a password and won't be a security issue.

2.) Can I still set up an automated script that will simply input the required password the second I'm prompted for a password?

Thanks for the help, guys. I just joined this site so apologies if I'm not clear or don't understand the etiquette yet.

Comment: I assure you, a gigantic RSA key is much more secure than any password.

Comment: @Wug (as long as it is stored securely, of course).  Also, [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1340366/1309332) may have some information about #2.

Comment: __they can't set a passwordless SSH to due to security reasons.__ - is just plain _wrong_