# How to make ssh receive the password from stdin ON WINDOWS

Tags: windows, batch-file, cygwin, openssh

Having read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340366/how-to-make-ssh-receive-the-password-from-stdin/42957663#42957663) and my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42957663/712506) there, I would like to do a similar thing on Windows.

My Linux solution is this:

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ $1 =~ password: ]] && cat || SSH_ASKPASS="$0" DISPLAY=nothing:0 exec setsid "$@"
```

How can I do a similar thing on Windows, something I can use like this from a Windows *Command Prompt* or batch file:

```
C:> echo password | pass ssh user@host ...
```

Points to note:

- `ssh` here was installed using the free edition of [crwsync](https://www.itefix.net/cwrsync). It uses Cygwin DLLs but does not require a Cygwin install.
- the solution should not require further dependencies: it work from a typical Windows *Command Prompt* or batch file.

*I'm looking for an answer to the above, even if the answer is "it can't be done". I know I can use keys (and their relative merits), or other tools such as Python/Paramiko, PuTTY `plink`, and so-on. I know I can do it in a Cygwin environment. I don't want to do those things... I need to do it from a plain old Windows command prompt or batch file without incurring additional dependencies because, if this is possible, it will reduce existing dependencies.*

Here is what I have so far:

```
@echo off
echo.%1 | findstr /C:"password">nul
if errorlevel 1 (
  set SSH_ASKPASS="%0"
  set DISPLAY="nothing:0"
  %*
) else (
  findstr "^"
)
```

The idea is to save that as, say `pass.bat` and use it like this:

```
C:> echo password | pass.bat ssh user@host ...
```

What happens is that the SSH session is launched but `ssh` still interactively prompts for the password. I think that, in theory, the script is ok becuse the below works:

```
C:> echo mypassword | pass.bat pass.bat "password"
mypassword
```

As far as [I understand](https://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-env.html), the underlying Cygwin DLLs should see the Windows environment so the setting of `SSH_ASKPASS` should propagate into `ssh`.

I think the problem is that `ssh` is connected to the terminal. According to `man ssh`, *If ssh needs a passphrase, it will read the passphrase from the current terminal if it was run from a terminal.* This is why I use `setsid` in the Linux example. I think a way to detach the process from the terminal in Windows is required but I am [not sure](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csliu/2009/03/20/windows-unix-and-ansi-c-api-comparison) there is one (I did try `start /B`).

So I'm stuck - I don't know enough about scripting windows to know what should work. Any solution that uses native windows techniques (i.e. batch or perhaps powershell) and does not require anything not available on a vanilla Windows would be welcome.

The solution will be used by a cross platform application that I am working on that needs to use SSH to interact with an external service. The current prototype version is Python and is aready wired up to launch `ssh` as a subprocess. The Linux version already uses the above method so I would like a Windows solution that does not require reworking of the application.

Answer (score 0):

SSH will never read password from stdin. I would give a shot `sshpass` utility, which is quite standard for this task. The other common solution is using `expect` script (which should work the same way on the Cygwin as on Linux).

Comment: I did say that I knew of those things and that I specifically was looking for a **native windows solution**, if there is one.