# Shell script to automate SSH login using password

Tags: ssh

I am trying to automate SSH login by using password. I can't use expect command or sshpass etc. So I am left with only option to use password directly.
Did lot of research in google and didn't get any solution... :(

Please help me with this.

The code I tried is.

```
#!/bin/bash
USERNAME=user1
PASSWORD=abcd1234
HOSTS="server01.mat.us"
ssh ${HOSTS} -l ${USERNAME} -p ${PASSWORD}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'd recommend to use ssh keys instead of password if it's possible.

This script can help you to upload your public key to desired remote machine:

https://github.com/aprey10/ssh-authorizer

Answer (score 17):

The OpenSSH `ssh` utility doesn't accept a password on the command line or on its standard input. This also applies to the `scp` and `sftp` file transfer utilities, which invoke `ssh` to make the SSH connection. I believe this is a deliberate decision on the part of the OpenSSH developers. You have these options available to you:

1. Use an [SSH key](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2) for authentication, instead of a password.
2. Use [sshpass](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sshpass), [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/), or a similar tool to invoke `ssh` through a TTY and automate responding to the password prompt.
3. Use (abuse) the SSH_ASKPASS feature to get `ssh` to get the password by running another program, described [here](https://debian-administration.org/article/587/pam_mount_and_sshfs_with_password_authentication) or [here](https://verynomagic.com/2015/06/say-no-to-sshpass.html), or in some of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1340366/13317).
4. Get the SSH server administrator to enable [host-based authentication](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Host-based_Authentication) and use that. Note that host-based authentication is only suitable for certain network environments. See additional notes [here](https://cert.uni-stuttgart.de/doc/ssh-host-based.en.html) and [here](https://arc.liv.ac.uk/SGE/howto/hostbased-ssh.html).
5. Write your own ssh client using perl, python, java, or your favorite language. There are ssh client libraries available for most modern programming languages, and you'd have full control over how the client gets the password.
6. Download the [ssh source code](https://www.openssh.com/portable.html) and build a modified version of `ssh` that works the way you want.
7. Use a different ssh client. There are [other ssh clients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_SSH_clients) available, both free and commercial. One of them might suit your needs better than the OpenSSH client.

Comment: Thank you Kenster.... :) But I don't have an option to use SSH key  or sshpass or expect etc. so apart from all these do we have any other way to automate the above SSH case?. Please let me know.

Comment: Add `plink` to that list. It can take the password as an argument (even if, from a security stand point, doing so is a very bad idea!)

Comment: @salva technically, that falls under the "other SSH packages" option. I didn't want to get into recommending/listing the alternative packages that are available. Also, the OP doesn't say what platform he is on.

Comment: `plink` works both in Windows and in Linux/UNIX systems.

Comment: can you show `plink` example? everyone is redirecting to this answer, but nobody shared `plink` sample. There are scenario where remote company do not have budget to setup ssh key based login.