# How do I write a shell file to type in a password under macOS?

Tags: ios, macos, shell, ssh, passwords

I'm working on a simple app that would automatically ssh into my iPhone and run some commands. The thing is that the ssh command asks fro password and I'm not exactly sure how do I write a shell file so it would automatically input that password. My code for now looks like this:

```
ssh root@192.168.1.19
<here should be a code to type in the root password>
nimbus help
<some other commands>
```

Nimbus is an app I'm running through ssh to remotely control the phone.

Comment: You should set up public key authentication.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shell script to automate SSH login using password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43526330/shell-script-to-automate-ssh-login-using-password)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way would probably be to use [key-based authentication](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys#Key-Based_SSH_Logins) and add the right SSH key to your `ssh-agent`.

If that's not possible or you absolutely want to use password-based authentication, you can use `sshpass`.

You'll have to install it either manually or, if you are using Homebrew, by adding the custom formula at `http://git.io/sshpass.rb`.

Homebrew won't officially package it:

> We won't add sshpass because it makes it too easy for novice SSH users to
>   ruin SSH's security.

So be careful.