# Crontab a git pull from SSH repository with password

Tags: git, ssh, cron, passwords

Can I pass a password in a crontab command pipe to make access to a git repository ssh server?
like

```
*/10  * * * cd /path/gitpath/ && git pull ssh://user:password@XXX.XX.XX.XXX/path/reporitory.git
```

Or it's better cron a bash script with password?

Comment: my suggestion will be bash script with password

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43526842/13317

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend setting up ssh public/private keys, if you can. That way you wouldn't need to use a password when pulling from the repo.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Generating-Your-SSH-Public-Key

https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/