# Send a password from a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, ssh

How to send a password from a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) to a newly opened [ssh](/questions/tagged/ssh) session from that same file?

When I try this:

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\"
start ssh.exe user@1.2.3.4
echo passwd
pause
```

It opens a new `cmd.exe` window for `ssh` session but enters the `passwd` in the old `cmd` window.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43526330/13317

Comment: I was hopping it should be possible to simulate the keyboard button presses :)