# Is there a way to do SSH password-less login when the server only allows keyboard-interactive authentication?

Tags: ssh

Suppose I've got a server `foo.com` which only allows keyboard-interactive authentication, and that I can't change this. This means I can do,

```
sshpass -p PASSWORD ssh foo.com
```

but I can't create public/private keys to log in without a password.

Now, I could just create an `alias ssh_foo="sshpass -p PASSWORD ssh foo.com"`, but then I have to create aliases for `scp`, for `sftp`, and in general it won't work for any other programs that use these, e.g. graphical programs based on `sftp` which mount remote folders. So I'm looking for a more generic solution.

In particular, is there any way to set up my `.ssh/config` file to allow password-less login in this case? This should then work for everything. I feel like some clever combination of `ProxyCommand` and `LocalCommand` might do it, but I can't figure out what.

(Note, I do understand the security implication of this, I'm just curious if you can do it)

Comment: While the bounty is a nice touch with all the close votes coming in, you should consider moving to one of the more appropriate sister sites. Either super user or server fault are better options than stack overflow. Not saying your question isn't interesting, just wrong venue

Comment: See if this works for you? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/469387/sshpass-in-ssh-config

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43526842/13317

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted using [`expect`](https://core.tcl-lang.org/expect/index)? According to the documentation it "[Expect] is a tool for automating interactive applications such as telnet, ftp, passwd, fsck, rlogin, tip, etc."

The [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect#Usage) Page for except is also a very good resource for examples as the ones on the Expect page are broken.

You can also use [`plink`](http://zzz.bwh.harvard.edu/plink/download.shtml) which you can download and compile. You can use the `-pw` argument to automate this.