# python ssh password prompt

Tags: python, ssh

I am trying to get automatic password passing upon prompt while using ssh.
normally, rsa keys are used to prevent password prompt but I can't guarantee every user is set up properly so i want the script to automatically set the password if given by the user

Here is the

```
ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "localhost", "python -c 'print \"I am running\"' "], shell=False,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> Password:
```

My tried solution was

```
import sys, subprocess

class GetPass():
    def __init__(self, password):
       self.password=str(password)
    def readline(self):
        return self.password

sys.stdin = GetPass('mypassword')
# test raw_input 3 time to verify
raw_input()    
>> 'mypassword'
raw_input()    
>> 'mypassword'
raw_input()    
>> 'mypassword'

# Now try sshing again
ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "localhost", "python -c 'print \"I am running\"' "], shell=False,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> Password:
```

This is not working as requesting password is still prompted.
The idea is that GetPass replacing sys.stdin will always return the desired password automatically without the user typing it himself.

any idea or solution ?

Comment: http://www.paramiko.org/

Comment: I know paramiko but i don't want to add dependencies and keep it simple if possible. thanks

Comment: You might consider using [`getpass`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html) (builtin) to collect the input rather than `raw_input`

Comment: the main idea is to avoid having to put the password not to used getpass. raw_input was to show that GetPass is working.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340366/how-to-make-ssh-receive-the-password-from-stdin

Comment: I didn't make it with paramiko. But [pexpect](http://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html), not pexpect.pxssh, works perfect.

Answer (score 2):

SSH reads the password from the terminal, not from stdin, so there's no way you can provide a synthetic (not prompted) password using `subprocess.Popen`.

I understand not wanting to lade your application with dependencies, but I also would recommend `paramiko` for this. Without that, you're looking at using a workflow manager like `pyexpect` for `fabric` anyway, unless you implement the whole workflow yourself using a pseudoterminal. You can do that without introducing dependencies, but frankly it's not worth the extra surface area for bugs or behavior divergence.

Still, if you want to try it, here's [a gist that outlines an approach](https://gist.github.com/virtuald/54c8657a9ea834fb7fdd). You could simplify this quite a lot but it gets the essentials across.