# Capture ssh password prompt in python

Tags: python, ssh

I would like to capture a ssh password prompt as string in python. For example:

```
> ssh user@hostname
user@hostname's password:
```

I need this string 'user@hostname's password:'.
A similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46004848/python-ssh-password-prompt) is asked here. 
I tried to use subprocess and paramiko, but I didn't manage to capture the string. Is there anyway to get it?

Comment: You might want to use `ssh_decorate`, rather than using paramiko directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solved]

Solved with [pexpect](http://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html). I can read this data from [pexpect.spawn](http://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pexpect.html#pexpect.spawn). A advantage of pexpect is that, by using [interact()](http://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pexpect.html#pexpect.spawn.interact) method, I can give back control to the interactive user (the human at the keyboard) after program processes the login, which is exactly what I want.

I can fetch the string 'user@hostname's password:' using [this method](https://gist.github.com/virtuald/54c8657a9ea834fb7fdd). However, if I want to give the interactive user control after login, it seems complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Although OP already answered this question, I believe sharing some actual Python code - based on `pexec`, as described in the accepted answer - will be useful:

```
import pexpect

child = pexpect.spawn("ssh user@localhost")
child.expect(".+") # Greedy match on everything that follows
print("Captured:", child.match.group(0))
```

The key part from [pexpect.expect()](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pexpect.html#pexpect.spawn)'s documentation:

> When a match is found for the given pattern, the class instance
> attribute match becomes an re.MatchObject result.