# ssh expect command with variables

Tags: shell, expect

I am planning to take password from file instead of passing parameter to the script

```
set cmd1 {`cat passwdfile.txt | grep -w pj |  cut -d";" -f5`}
spawn ssh username@servername

expect "password: "
send "$cmd1\r"
expect "$ "
send "ps -ef |grep planning1\r"
expect "$ "
send "exit\r"
```

Error

```
    username@servername's password:
    Permission denied, please try again.
```

Why it is not taking password from the file ??

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340366/how-to-make-ssh-receive-the-password-from-stdin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the point where ssh is asking for a password, you don't have access to a shell, so the backticks and all the rest will be sent as plain characters as the password.

Assuming that file exists on your local machine, get the password before you spawn:

```
set pw [exec grep -w pj passwdfile.txt | cut -d\; -f5]
spawn ssh ...
expect "password: "
send "$pw\r"
```

Of course it's terribly insecure to store passwords in plain text. You should set up ssh keys to allow you to log in without having to type a password.

Comment: thank u glenn.. i am storing password for time being .. i will delete the file immediately after my steps are completed.i will try this

Comment: when i run this i am getting below error                                                  i am using expect ./scriptname                                                                                     
 cut: you must specify a list of bytes, characters, or fields
Try `cut --help' for more information.
    while executing
"exec grep -w pj passwdfile.txt | cut -d'"
    invoked from within
"set pw [exec grep -w pj passwdfile.txt | cut -d';' -f5]"
    (file "./1.sh" line 4)

Comment: it seems to be interpreting the semicolon as the end of the command. Oh, the single quotes are the problem: single quotes have no special meaning in Tcl, so the semicolon is not quoted or escaped. Try `cut -d\; -f5`