# How to enter password of cluster using python script

Tags: python, cluster-computing, hpc

I am trying to write a python script which uses `scp` to log into a HPC cluster (where I have an account) and transfer files from the cluster to my local system. I am able to `os.system()` to type the `scp` command. But, after that, I am a bit confused about what I must do when I am asked for the password (assume my password is `password`). I have tried `os.system('password')` and print `'password'`, but they don't work.

This is the python script that I have written:

```
import os
import sys

password = 'password'
clusterpath = 'myname@cluster.hpc1.cs.univ.edu:/Projects/re* '
localpath = 'Projects/.'
os.system('scp ' + clusterpath  + localpath)
```

When I execute this script, I am asked for the password of my cluster. How can I enter the password of the cluster account through this python script?

Comment: Not really a Python answer for your question, but maybe you should be using the SSH key pair authentication, so that you just needed to `ssh-add` and type your SSH key password once, then run your script multiple times without being asked for it again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make ssh receive the password from stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340366/how-to-make-ssh-receive-the-password-from-stdin)