# Restarting Linux m/c Programmatically

Tags: java, linux, runtime.exec

I am new to Linux help me on the following:

How to restart the linux machine using Java and it tried using Runtime.exec method using the following command **sudo shutdown -r now** and it asks for password, how do i proceed from here.Please help me out.

Comment: Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233217/pass-password-to-su-sudo-ssh

Comment: It is difficult to supply "sudo" with a password programmatically. Also the password then needs to be managed (i.e. how does it handle changes? How is it protected from unauthorised access etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to configure sudo so that your user does not require a password to execute the reboot command.

This is straightforward; read the man page for sudoers.

The command

```
reboot
```

Is a shortcut.