# can we write a simple bash script to automatically login as root user

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu-10.04, ubuntu-11.04, ubuntu-10.10

I usually have to login in 20 to 50 times daily as a super user, typing the long password again and again..

i have just created a simple bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo -s
echo password
```

./test

output root@localhost:
password
when i execute it, it works like charm... but it shows my password on the screen.....

do some one have any other best solution...... for this small problem.......

i hope this is not all the solution in security standard...... can we have any other solution with out exposing my password.....

Comment: You know, showing your password on-screen is the least of your problems if you have a shell script that automatically sudoes. Hopefully it's owned by your user and not executable (or readable...) by any group.

Comment: you could just set up sudo to not require a password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure `sudo` to require a password only every so many minutes. The default is 5 minutes. Read the `sudoers` man page and scroll down to this:

```
    timestamp_timeout
               Number of minutes that can elapse before sudo will ask
               for a passwd again.  The timeout may include a
               fractional component if minute granularity is
               insufficient, for example 2.5.  The default is 5.  Set
               this to 0 to always prompt for a password.  If set to a
               value less than 0 the user's timestamp will never
               expire.  This can be used to allow users to create or
               delete their own timestamps via sudo -v and sudo -k
               respectively.
```

Answer (score 4):

You can pipe the echo'd password into a command.  Try something like this:

```
echo myPassword | sudo -S
```

You can see come more info on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233217/pass-password-to-su-sudo-ssh).

Question is, do you REALLY want your password in a shell script file? (just emphasizing that its a terrible idea)

Comment: Definitely don do this, unless you want everybody could read root password using ps

Comment: Agreed, was just answering the question :P

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason that you can't `sudo su -` to just become the root user instead of prepending all of your commands with `sudo blah`?

Answer (score 1):

just change ownership of the script to root & set SUID-Bit in user the permissions

chmod u=rws g+x o+x script123

the script will run as root for every user

Answer (score 0):

simple solution is to use key base authentication 
Use ssh-copy-id instead following from this [tutorial](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/) which is secure