# Ant exec task as another user

Tags: ant, exec, debian

I would like to execute a shell script from an ant build (I saw the exec task seems to do it), but this script has to be executed from a user different thant the one launching ant. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [sshsexec](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshexec.html) task. Connect locally or to a remote machine:

```
<sshexec host="localhost"
    username="dude"
    password="yo"
    command="touch somefile"/>
```

This task will require the optional [jsch.jar](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/index.html) to be installed in your ANT lib.

Specifying a pirvate key would enable a password-less login.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you execute, from ant, a script that executes the actual script using `sudo`? See [How to pass the password to su/sudo/ssh without overriding the TTY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233217/pass-password-to-su-sudo-ssh) for how to pass the password from the command line.

Comment: I tried this using bash (default terminal) and it works. ANT, however, doesn't seem to be able to execute the trick and seems to not read the password:
     [exec] 
     [exec] Password:
     [exec] Sorry, try again.
     [exec] Password:
     [exec] Sorry, try again.
     [exec] Password:
     [exec] Sorry, try again.