# Being able to run jar from link in Linux

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, jar, runtime

To make my program a bit more user friendly and easy to update, when it installs it creates a link to the .jar file is on the desktop.

The problem is- The file is not marked as executable, so the user would have to find a hidden directory and mark the jar file as executable. Blech.

I tried using:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"sudo","chmod","+x",home+"/"+dir+"/DevChat.jar"});
```

, which, foresee-ably, requested the user's password which went without reply.

So is there any way I could 
A) Give runtime the user's password after prompting the user for it,
B) Make the link run the command "java -jar blahblahblah.jar", or
C) Write an install script that marks the file as executable?

Comment: Putting a link to an application on the desktop is a Windows paradigm—it's not really done on *nix flavors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to be root to change the permissions of a filesystem object you own.

Comment: By George... you're right! Tons of thanks! A tutorial on bash had me thinking root was necessary...
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As someone said ... you don't need to be root to change the permissions of the jar file.
 However, in case this file is placed in a folder where administrator privileges are needed to access it or there is no workaround for that just use the -S option when running sudo.
For reference check here: [Getting stdin from sudo command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233217/pass-password-to-su-sudo-ssh) ;)
Cheers pal!

P.S.: Of course, you have to open a stream and then get that from the terminal which I assume is trivial in your case. If you do have a problem however just ask.

Comment: That's pretty cool! I'm sure another occasion will come along when I need to use this

Comment: Glad that I was of some help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you created a link in the desktop, I'm going to assume you want some kind of GUI based intereaction with the user.

If so, just use gksudo instead of sudo.

```
   Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"gksudo","chmod","+x",home+"/"+dir+"/DevChat.jar"});
```

If you need something a bit more complex, take a look at [Zenity](http://live.gnome.org/Zenity).

Comment: Hey, that's brilliant! While it may not be used in this application, this will definitely come in handy!