# how to execute sudo command with ant sshexec

Tags: ant, command, sudo

i'm trying to execute a command in a remote server with sudo like this

```
<target name="remote-test">
    <sshexec host="${remote.host}"
        username="${remote.user}"
        password="${remote.pass}"
        trust="true"
        usepty="true"
        command="sudo ls /home/myuser" />
</target>
```

But the server response the following:

```
Buildfile: build.xml
remote-test:
  [sshexec] Connecting to 0.0.0.0:22
  [sshexec] cmd : sudo ls /home/myuser
  [sshexec] [sudo] password for myuser:
```

So, how i can use ant to execute a remote command with sudo?

Thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing a password to "su" command over sshexec from ant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919381/passing-a-password-to-su-command-over-sshexec-from-ant)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, maybe it can be duplicated like this:

[How to pass the password to su/sudo/ssh without overriding the TTY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233217/pass-password-to-su-sudo-ssh)

But anyway, one solution to this problems is like says in the most voted answer of the

```
<target name="remote-test-jboss">
    <sshexec host="${remote.host}"
        username="${remote.user}"
        password="${remote.pass}"
        command="echo ${remote.pass}| sudo -S ls /home/myserver" 
        trust="true"
    />
</target>
```

The -S parameter is for read from standart input.