# Switch user without prompting for a password in shell script

Tags: shell, scripting

I need to switch between two users using a shell script.

I used su and sudo for switching between users. The bottom line is that, it's prompting for user password every time, and I do not want that to happen.

I know the password; is there a way I can hard code it in the script itself, so that it will not prompt the user for a password?

Comment: show what you have done and tried?

Comment: `su root
    systemctl restart postgresql.service`
part of my code

Comment: see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7747/is-it-possible-to-su-without-being-prompted-for-a-password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't a `NOPASSWD` clause in `sudoers` work? For example:

```
user1 ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/su user2
```

Allows `user1` to su to `user2` without password. If you only need to run a certain command as `user2`, add that to `sudoers` (through `visudo`) explicitly:

```
user1 ALL=(user2) NOPASSWD: /path/to/command
```

Then as `user1` run:

```
sudo -k user2 /path/to/command
```

Answer (score 1):

With the `-S` parameter `sudo` accepts the password from Standard Input. See: [How to pass the password to su/sudo/ssh without overriding the TTY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233217/pass-password-to-su-sudo-ssh)