# No response from Selenium Server when starting from jar file

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid2

I am setting up a headless Ubuntu server as a node.  This node runs Chrome via Chromedriver, and I am able to run tests when I launch the jar via bash.  This is the command I am using:

```
java -jar /opt/selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar -role node -hub 
http://qwautomation02:4444/grid/register -port 5555 
-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/opt/chromedriver.exe -nodeConfig /mnt/smb/Configuration/nodeConfig.json
```

I have written a Java application to run this command and insert the ports that are being used into a database.  This application uses the same bash command to start the Selenium server as above.  I am launching this jar from the /opt directory, the same directory that the Selenium server jar is in.  Here is the applicable method:

```
    public static Process startupNode(int portNumber, String browser) throws IOException{
    //If Linux, else Windows.
    String port = String.valueOf(portNumber);
    if (Portability.isUnix()) {
        return Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String.format("java -jar /opt/selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar -role node -hub http://qwautomation02:4444/grid/register -port %s -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/opt/chromedriver -nodeConfig /mnt/smb/Configuration/nodeConfig.json"
                , port));   
    }
    else
        return Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String.format("java -jar C:\\Selenium\\vendor\\selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar -role node -hub http://qwautomation02:4444/grid/register -port %s -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\\Chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe -nodeConfig \\\\qwautomation02\\WebDriver\\Configuration\\nodeConfig.json"
                , port));   
}
```

I can start a test and part of runs, but this exception is always thrown during execution and cannot be caught.

[image: Exception being thrown]

It appears that the session is losing communication with the hub in mid execution.  But, considering the test will run to completion when I manually run the bash command, I am at a loss for why this is occurring.

Comment: Try adding some wait hust before the line of Exception. From https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/selenium-users/1im-LurjK5s

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an Ubuntu permissions error. Your personal Ubuntu user has execute access, but the user / process that is running the java file may not.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015829/how-to-supply-sudo-with-root-password-from-java
I'm going to try implementing the answer from here.  The actual jar executes, though.  It just has communication issues with the other server.  I wasn't sure if it could be an issue with getRuntime().exec on the same thread as the main thread that has a ReadLine() statement to keep the jar running.

Comment: It also could be a polling timeout with the hub. I've run into that with more complex element selectors.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: Sure, I'd love to. The Selenium Webdriver Grid / Hub mode, when run in parallel will sometimes lockup while waiting for callbacks from each node. My setup is an Ubuntu Host running 3 VM Images of various configs of Windows and IE. The selenium hub runs in Ubuntu, and the nodes run in Windows.

Comment: Optimization advice: http://blogs.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/posts/07-07-16/selenium-ie-performance-issues-tests-optimization