# How to use tee with sshpass in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a situation that I need to append several lines(ip and hosts) from a file to /etc/hosts.

If I execute the below command

> **sshpass -p password cat /tmp/hosts |sudo tee -a  /etc/hosts**

I am getting

> sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified.
> Sorry, try again.
>
> sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified. Sorry, try again.
>
> sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified. Sorry, try again.
>
> sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts

Any alternatives to this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with sshpass: does it work with sudo? It sounds ssh-specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
sudo -S sh -c 'cat /tmp/hosts >> /etc/hosts' <<< "password"
```

It's best to contain redirections for sudo within a subshell so that the elevated permissions are applied to opening the destination file.

ref: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4327123/7552

Answer (score 0):

The error you face comes from the fact that `sshpass` tries to send the password to  `cat`, not to `sudo`. Your command line should have, in theory, looked rather like this:

```
cat /tmp/hosts |sshpass -p password sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
```

but `sshpass` does not forward `stdin` to `sudo` so this is a dead end. (`sudo` does forward `stdin` though that is why something like `sudo tee` works)

**You could do something like this**

```
sshpass -p password sudo echo "Hello"
cat /tmp/hosts | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
```

so that the second call to `sudo` does not require a password.

**Another option** is to embed the `cat` and the redirection in a shell script and then just

```
sshpass -p password sudo ./thescript.sh
```

**Or you can**, as @glennjackman wrote, embed the `cat` and the redirection in a subshell:

```
sshpass -p password sudo sh -c 'cat /tmp/hosts >> /etc/hosts'
```

**And of course**, you can configure `sudo` to [not require passwords](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192050/how-to-run-sudo-command-with-no-password).