# RSpec intercepting backticks, preventing sudo?

Tags: ruby, rspec

RSpec intercepting backticks, preventing sudo?

I'm porting some code from MiniTest to RSpec.  Said code now fails.

In IRB:

```
`sudo echo 1`   # returns 1
```

RSpec:

```
# example.rb
class Example
  def self.doexec
    `sudo echo 1`
  end
end

# example_spec.rb
it '#doexec' do
  Example.doexec.should include("1")
end
```

...when executed:

```
rspec spec/lib/example_spec.rb
# spec fails, stderror:
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Is this a bug, feature, or any idea of how to work it (without hardwiring in the password)?

Comment: You should run it from console.. then it will ask you root password, and you need to give it, and then it will run.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way, you can try :-

## test.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class Example
  def self.do_this
    `echo <your password> | sudo -S echo 11`
  end
end
```

## test_spec.rb

```
require_relative "../test.rb"

describe Example do
  it '#do_this' do
    expect(Example.do_this).to include("1")
  end
end
```

Now run your file :-

```
arup@linux-wzza:~/Ruby> rspec spec/test_spec.rb
root's password:.

Finished in 0.07274 seconds (files took 0.13673 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

Read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233217/pass-password-to-su-sudo-ssh).