# Running a program in the background as sudo

Tags: linux, sudo

I am on a linux virtual machine and I'm trying to run the command `sudo synaptic &` which should start synaptic in the background. However, it doesn't ask for the password and the program doesn't seem to start. I have not typed my password earlier, as running any other command withouth the & at the end ask for my password. What is the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [pass password to su/sudo/ssh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233217/pass-password-to-su-sudo-ssh)

Comment: Did you log in your virtual machine as "root"? If so, you are running with root privilege, and be careful with that.

Comment: Trying to background something – *anything* – with sudo immediately raises a couple of red flags. What's the actual problem you're trying to solve? Did you try running it as a service managed by your supervisor suite (systemd, runit, OpenRC or whatever else your system is using)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can run `sudo bash -c 'synaptic &'`

Answer (score 13):

sudo --help says about option -b

```
-b, --background              run command in the background
```

This worked for me

```
sudo -b su -c "command what you want to run"
```

Comment: apparently you can just run the command after `sudo -b`, you don't need the inner su -c

Comment: @joe_zeroh You do need the inner `su -c`. Here is an example with trying to open gedit. Open a new terminal and execute `sudo -b gedit &`. All you will see is e.g. `[1] 9258` in the terminal; there will be no prompt for password and the gedit window will not open. Now open another terminal and execute `sudo -b "gedit &"`. This time you will be prompted for password, but after that, you will get the error `sudo: gedit &: command not found`. Finally, execute `sudo -b su -c "gedit &"`. Now everything works as it should.

Comment: For me it works without the inner su. I just tried with sudo -b xed /etc/hosts. The password prompt comes in the terminal before xed is started and set to background. BTW, this is the best answer IMO.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the `sudo` command itself is being run in the background. As a result, it will be stopped (SIGSTOP) when it tries to access the standard input to read the password.

A simple solution is to create a shell script to run `synaptic &` and then `sudo` the script in the foreground (i.e. without `&`).

Comment: Could you include a link to describe  'synaptic &'

Answer (score 0):

From the previous answer, only adding `-b` to a command starting with `sudo` might work, as below:

```
sudo -b COMMAND
```

Worked for the command below:

```
sudo -b mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

*Note. For a non-sudo command, there's nohup, as below:*

```
nohup COMMAND &
```

*Adding `nohup` before the command, and an `&` after the command might work for a non-`sudo` command.*