# Passing su password in shell script

Tags: shell, sudo, su

How can password be passed in a shell script using su(without sudo and except)?.
I have tried echo "password" | su root -c  .But it didnt work.

Comment: **Are you crazy?** Never, ever put the root password in a script (or use it in a command in a way it is captured in the `history` file). That is just asking for trouble. The proper way to `su` or `sudo` to root without a password is to make yourself a member of the `wheel` group, then `su` to root (give password), edit sudo config `visudo` and add the following line at the end `%wheel  ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`. Then you and all members of the `wheel` group can `su` or `sudo` without being prompted for a password.

Comment: Why did this get downvotes?  Aside from making the tactical error of suggesting a solution that would expose the root password, this is a good question about how to pipe passwords to the `su` utility.

Comment: A [near-identical question on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/354838/is-there-a-single-line-command-to-do-su) got 12 upvotes and two decent, upvoted answers.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233217/how-to-pass-the-password-to-su-sudo-ssh-without-overriding-the-tty is a near-duplicate, but none of the upvoted answers address passing passwords to `su` specifically (only `sudo` and `ssh`).

Answer (score 5):

The best way of doing this is with `sudo`, but since you don't want the best solution, you can you can use `script` instead:

```
{ sleep 3; echo "yourpassword"; } | script -q -c 'su -c whoami' /dev/null
```

This will print `root`, the output of `whoami`.

Please make sure to try this command verbatim (with password replaced) before trying to adapt it to run your own commands, since adapting it is difficult and error prone.