# echo password with command in ubuntu terminal

Tags: matlab, qt, ubuntu

I am using a remote supercomputer to run my c++ code, written in qt creator and build in Ubuntu. I try to run my code using Matlab dos command in order to run multiple copy of my c++ code using parfor. During running, each code I need to input password. Therefore, my question is: how should I pass password to command terminal in Ubuntu? I tried following code but it did not work.

```
sudo ./MyCode 10 <\$(read -sp "Password: " myPassword; echo $password)

sudo ./MyCode 10 ----> this command work but it require entering the password I want to get rid of entering password.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4327123/6219719 - How to pass the password to sudo.

Comment: thank you very much