# Standard Input setting after configuring process.launchPath = "/usr/bin/sudo" in swift

Tags: swift, process, sudo

It is handle after I configuring taskOuput's launchPath to "/usr/bin/sudo". How can I modify the code to make it works?

```
let theTask = Process()
let stdin = FileHandle(forReadingAtPath:"c")
let taskOutput = Pipe()
theTask.launchPath = "/usr/bin/sudo"
theTask.standardOutput = taskOutput
theTask.standardInput = stdin
theTask.standardError = taskOutput
theTask.arguments = ["mkdir", "/usr/local/newfolder"]
theTask.launch()
theTask.waitUntilExit()
```

Comment: See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233217/how-to-pass-the-password-to-su-sudo-ssh-without-overriding-the-tty about the "-S" option (and its risks)..

Comment: thank you. it works