# How to switch user in bat file when you login to standard user and then su to other user on ssh to linux server?

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, sudo, su

i am doing automation the process by bat file.

```
putty.exe -ssh bhavepatel@10.10.178.140 -pw Winter34! -m C:\Users\BHAVEPATEL\Desktop\tel\tel.txt -t
```

In tel.txt file , i want to change the directory ans switch the user.Please see below code in tel.txt file

```
 cd /apps/denodo/bin 
 sudo -su denodo bash; /bin/bash
```

Putty prompt with pwd  when i swith the user to denodo. How can i pass the password input to bat file?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Not in an interactive session.

See [How to pass the password to su/sudo/ssh without overriding the TTY?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/233217/850848)

All you can do is to configure `sudo` not to ask for a password at all. That's the only legitimate approach. To admin that you are actually logging in without typing a password. Instead of secretly automating password typing.

See [How to avoid prompt password for sudo?](https://askubuntu.com/q/470383/280048)