# Swift/ MacOS: Process launch with root permissions

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

My app should check if a service is currently running or not. 
In terminal the command would be

```
sudo launchctl list | grep some_service
```

I can't seem to be able to find any resources to create and use a privileged helper to run the protected command.

I have however found this rather rough [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42493290/launch-sudo-command-from-macos-app-swift), but is it safe?

Also, is it possible to just elevate the permissions of the app to just run as root everytime? If so how would I do it?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

The Cocoa equivalent of `launchctl list` is [SMCopyAllJobDictionaries(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/servicemanagement/1431086-smcopyalljobdictionaries) in the ServiceManagement framework.

It's deprecated for a while but it still works.

A privileged helper can be created with [SMJobBless(*:*:*:*:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/servicemanagement/1431078-smjobbless?preferredLanguage=swift) and an XPC service, but this is not trivial to accomplish.

Comment: Yes, I explored the XPC / JobBless and it's not trivial at all! Similarly I would have to use `SMJobBless` for say starting or stopping a system service?