# Privileged file copy in macOS (Installing a helper binary to /usr/local/bin)

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I have a helper binary `mytool` inside my main app bundle that I need to copy to `/usr/local/bin`.

Now `bin` might not always exist or have write access, so the standard `NSWorkspace` calls will fail on it. I looked into different ways to do this, but none are satisfactory (or I am doing it wrong)

1. Getting an authorization for `replaceFile` for `NSWorkspace.requestAuthorization`

   This does not seem to work, as I still get a privileges error after trying to "replace" the file in `/usr/local/bin/mytool` with the one from my bundle.
2. Manually getting Authorization via `AuthorizationCreate`.

   The problem here is that `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges` is deprecated (or in my case not even available in Swift), and `SMJobBless` seems to be only for longer running helper processes. Also `SMJobBless`requires my helper tool to have an `Info.plist` of its own, which it doesn't have since its just a plain binary

So how do I manage to perform a privileged file copy in Swift?

PS: The app is not sandboxed, so `NSOpenPanel` does not help.

Comment: Use `NSOpenPanel` and point `directoryURL` to /usr/local/bin.  And ask the user to select it.

Comment: Well, `Kaleidoscope` for instance does it without an `NSOpenPanel` (which is a horrible experience). So there must be a way to do this... or they are using deprecated API.

Comment: Ask the user for the password and then use `Process` to execute the commands using sudo. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68229559/9223839) for an example of handling sudo and password

Comment: You can't use sudo for Mac App Store applications to my knowledge.

Comment: Big security OOF. I really don't want to ask for sudo passwords. @ElTomato doesn't have to support MAS though. Can't use external helpers in the MAS version anyway

Comment: I don't know what the Kaleidoscope guy is.  BBEdit uses `NSOpenPanel` and has the user select a file path if I remember correctly.  That's what I do as well.

Comment: Note that sudo password here is the users normal password, so I am not talking about some kind of root access. It's quite common for apps to ask for password to install or do something on a system level but maybe this is then used with some specific API.

Comment: "Also SMJobBlessrequires my helper tool to have an Info.plist of its own, which it doesn't have since its just a plain binary" That's what I thought too, but it turns out that plain old executables on macOS (in the Mach O object format) can embed arbitrary files into "sections", including the `info.plist` and `bundle.plist`. Search for "other linker flags" on this page: https://www.woodys-findings.com/posts/cocoa-implement-privileged-helper

Comment: This tutorial covers *exactly* this. Installing a CLI tool into `/usr/local/bin`: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hPEDjbb_BD0

Comment: @Alexander I know how to do it, I was just looking for a good **non-deprecated** way to do it. But apparently there is none.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I dug out the deprecated API using `dlsym`, because there is simply no other way besides asking the user manually for his password, which I don't want to do unless the deprecated API disappears entirely.

So what I do now is authenticate a call to `mytool --install` using `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges` like this:

```
import Foundation
import Security

public struct Sudo {

    private typealias AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivilegesImpl = @convention(c) (
        AuthorizationRef,
        UnsafePointer<CChar>, // path
        AuthorizationFlags,
        UnsafePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>?>, // args
        UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<FILE>>?
    ) -> OSStatus

    /// This wraps the deprecated AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges
    /// and makes it accessible by Swift
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - path: The executable path
    ///   - arguments: The executable arguments
    /// - Returns: `errAuthorizationSuccess` or an error code
    public static func run(path: String, arguments: [String]) -> Bool {
        var authRef: AuthorizationRef!
        var status = AuthorizationCreate(nil, nil, [], &authRef)

        guard status == errAuthorizationSuccess else { return false }
        defer { AuthorizationFree(authRef, [.destroyRights]) }

        var item = kAuthorizationRightExecute.withCString { name in
            AuthorizationItem(name: name, valueLength: 0, value: nil, flags: 0)
        }
        var rights = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &item) { ptr in
            AuthorizationRights(count: 1, items: ptr)
        }

        status = AuthorizationCopyRights(authRef, &rights, nil, [.interactionAllowed, .preAuthorize, .extendRights], nil)

        guard status == errAuthorizationSuccess else { return false }

        status = executeWithPrivileges(authorization: authRef, path: path, arguments: arguments)

        return status == errAuthorizationSuccess
    }

    private static func executeWithPrivileges(authorization: AuthorizationRef,
                                              path: String,
                                              arguments: [String]) -> OSStatus {
        let RTLD_DEFAULT = dlopen(nil, RTLD_NOW)
        guard let funcPtr = dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges") else { return -1 }
        let args = arguments.map { strdup($0) }
        defer { args.forEach { free($0) }}
        let impl = unsafeBitCast(funcPtr, to: AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivilegesImpl.self)
        return impl(authorization, path, [], args, nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this using public APIs (meaning not using deprecated APIs, invoking Apple Script, shelling out via Process, etc.) then the only way to achieve this is using `SMJobBless`. For better or worse, that's the only option still officially supported by Apple.

If you want to install your binary in `/usr/local/bin` then that binary itself doesn't need to have an Info.plist. You'd want to create a *different* helper tool which would be installed via `SMJobBless` that could copy your binary to `/usr/bin/local`. It will be able to do that because a helper tool installed by `SMJobBless` always runs as root. Once you're done with all of this you could have the helper tool you installed with `SMJobBless` uninstall itself. No denying it's rather involved.

If you do want to go down this route, take a look at [SwiftAuthorizationSample](https://github.com/trilemma-dev/SwiftAuthorizationSample).

Comment: Thats exactly what I do not want to do since its even worse than using deprecated API.

Comment: Of course it’s your choice. From a complexity point of view it’s definitely way higher. The way in which it’s better is that it’s 100% supported. Apple does in many cases eventually fully remove deprecated APIs.