# How can I pass a password from a file to the "su" command?

Tags: bash, shell, su, switch-user

How can I pass password to su command in shell script from another text file.

password.txt is like

```
password=tryme
```

shell script need to be ran by user gucq1

shell script is like

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /pstools/85419/jre/bin
java -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2 -jar /app1/nohr/soft/85419/gucq1/cust/classes/SVC_TestS.jar
```

I need to run this script with different id (gucq1) than I am logged in with (autoid).

I dont want to use SUDO as I dont have access to it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233217/how-to-pass-the-password-to-su-sudo-ssh-without-overriding-the-tty is a superset of this question. The OP there accepted an answer that doesn't cover explicitly your aspect, but other answers do address your needs. That said, from a security perspective, you should *never ever* do this.

Comment: It's safer to generate a SSH keypair and install an `authorized_keys` entry in `gucq1/.ssh` that allows that key to only run the one specific script -- that way if the key is stolen the user can only run that script as `gucq1`, not have complete and total control of the account.

Comment: If you have `password.txt` and access to `su`, you can *give* yourself access to `sudo`. Make use of it.

Comment: @chepner, that's only if the OP can su to root; they're su'ing to a different user here. But that *does* let them set up `authorized_keys`.

Comment: Clearly I've forgotten how `su` works

Answer (score -1):

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/113754/allow-user1-to-su-user2-without-password#115090

if you change your `/etc/pam.d/su`, you can use

```
su gucq1 -c <command>
```

without `su` prompting for password.

Comment: If the OP doesn't have sudo access, is it reasonable to expect them to have write to the PAM configuration?

Comment: i assumed he did not have the sudo utility installed, rather than not have root access.

Answer (score -1):

Although I dont recommend it, you can use SUDO like this.

```
echo "mypassword" | sudo -S ./somescript ;
```

Regards!