# SSH into server, sudo later with Phing

Tags: ssh, phing

We have a server that is set up so you can't log in with root directly. You first log in with a user, then run su and enter the password.

I need to SSH into a server, using phing, and sudo then run a command. I thought if I can get it working just via `ssh`, I can use that command in an exec task in phing, but can't even get the plain SSH right.

Is this possible?

I've tried the following:

```
ssh user@server 'su && cd /var/www/clients'
ssh user@server 'su && {{password}} && cd /var/www/clients'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [SshTask](https://www.phing.info/phing/guide/en/output/hlhtml/#SshTask) and [how-to-pass-the-password-to-su-sudo-ssh-without-overriding-the-tty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233217/how-to-pass-the-password-to-su-sudo-ssh-without-overriding-the-tty).

```
<project name="ssh-with-later-sudo" default="run-cmd" basedir=".">
    <target name="run-cmd">
        <ssh username="user" password="password" host="server" command="echo password | sudo -S cd /var/www/clients" />
    </target>
</project>
```