# Pass password twice using sshpass

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I need to create `/etc/apt/apt.conf` on a remote server and add proxy details to it over ssh.

```
sshpass -p pass123 ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no user@10.10.4.4 -p 234 cat <<EOL | 'sudo cat > /etc/apt/apt.conf'
Acquire::http::proxy "http://proxy.my.org.com:80"; 
Acquire::https::proxy "http://proxy.my.org.com:80/";
EOL
```

but it fails with `-bash: /etc/apt/apt.conf: Permission denied` .

On logging to the remote server, if I do `vi /etc/apt/apt.conf` it prompts for password.

How can I pass password twice, one during initial login and next during sudo ?

Comment: `sshpass` is just for the local `ssh` command, it's not for sending passwords to other commands that are executed.

Comment: @How can I remotely create that file ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass the password to su/sudo/ssh without overriding the TTY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233217/how-to-pass-the-password-to-su-sudo-ssh-without-overriding-the-tty)

Comment: Simple echo password and piping that to `tee` worked